# Can Apache settings stop Adobe Flash movies from decoding HTML entities sent as part of a GET Request?

Tags: php, flash, apache

I have just inherited a site to look after, previous developers worked with PHP / Flash. part of it generates EMBED tags to display a SWF file. This calls has a few parameters sent as part of the URL which the Flash movie uses to place text.

PHP script is doing the right thing by URL encoding all the parameters, but it seems that the Flash movie is unable to decode these.

This has started happening recently, I am suspecting that something has changed in later versions of Flash Player causing this issue.

However I thought it might be nice to confirm that Flash doesn't require any Apache level variables to be set to ensure it can URL decode properly.

And thoughts are much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. Flash is client-side, it does not depend on Apache settings